# Loop through foreach array

Tags: php, jquery, arrays, loops

I'm having a problem looping through my array to get just one value each time. I want to gray only 1 value because I'm calling that value in jquery. I'm new and sorry if this is too basic but I've been trying for days, pulling my hair out!

```
$designslist = array('design1','design2','design3','design4');
$current_index = 0;
$current_id = current($designslist);
$next = $designslist[$current_index + 1];

foreach( $designslist as $value )
{
  if( $value !== $next )continue;
  $nexts =  $next;
  echo $nexts;
  $current_index++;
}
```

Inside my html

```
<a href="#" id="<?php echo $nexts; ?>">next</a>
```

calling the id with jquery

```
$('#design1').on('click',function() {
  $('#web1').removeClass().addClass('big1');
});
```

Comment: when asking a question, always make sure to indent your code and not mix tabs and spaces, because you want people to be able to read your code =) On a secondary note, don't use `<a href="#">` anchors. This is a leftover from html 3.2, under html5 (and html 4.01) rules, this link will actually take you to the top of the page.

Comment: can u explain clearly, what u want to do with the loo[p

Comment: what is the output that you want?? can you please tell what you are trying to do with the loop???

Comment: //My array Array ( [0] => design1 [1] => design2 [2] => design3 [3] => design4 ) I want the output design1 then next time i click the link design2 and so on

Comment: Well I've tried everything everyone has recomended but I still can't get it to do what I want. if anyone else has any suggestions please enlighten me. Thanks guys!

Answer (score 2):

```
foreach( $designslist as $value )
```

needs to be

```
foreach( $designslist as $i => $value )
```

`$i` is the array index

Comment: //My array 
    Array ( [0] => design1 [1] => design2 [2] => design3 [3] => design4 )

    //set the current index?
    $current_id = current($designslist);

    //Next equals
    $next = $designslist[$i + 1];

    $i = 0;

    foreach( $designslist as $i => $value )
        if( $value !== $next )continue;
        $nexts =  $next;
        echo $nexts;
    $i++;
    }  what i need to do is loop through my array and get the design to be added into my <a href="" id="HERE"> which will keep looping each time I click the link. Thanks for all your help.

Answer (score 0):

You can try array search

```
$tag       = array_search($value, $designslist);
$nexts     = $$designslist[$tag];
```

Answer (score 0):

Ok, you seem to be mixing for with foreach using these "current_id" and "next" variables.

You can use this kind of [foreach](https://www.php.net/manual/en/control-structures.foreach.php) statement:

```
foreach ($designList as $key => $value) {
    echo "The key of $value is $key";
}
```

As you want to return only unique values, you should use the "[array_unique](https://www.php.net/function.array-unique)" function. Try this:

```
foreach (array_unique($designList) as $key => $value) {
    echo "The key of $value is $key";
}
```

I know it's not related to the question, but, as you said you're new to this, there are some PHP tips you should follow.

You're mixing snake_case with camelCase in your variables. I recommend using camelCase, but it's up to you.

Comment: //My array Array ( [0] => design1 [1] => design2 [2] => design3 [3] => design4 ) $current_id = current($designslist); $next = $designslist[$i + 1];--foreach( $designslist as $i => $value ){if( $value !== $next )continue;
            $nexts =  $next;
   echo $nexts;
   $i++;} how do I echo out design1 then next time i click the link it should be design2 and so on

Comment: You'll will need a variable in your JS to count the current "i", so you can get the next one. I think you should create a new question, focused in the JS / JQuery part!